# How to Navigate from one form to another in c#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I am creating a Windows desktop application in c# that has a Login Page Form and a MainView Form. I would like to navigate from Login form to MainView Form. how can i go about?

Comment: Kindly come clear where it is a windows phone application or desktop application because each has different classes for navigating from one form to another

Comment: Do you simply mean you want to navigate to another MainPage by chance?.. :)

Answer (score 0):

For making windows forms using C#

Initialize a new object of the Mainview and show it, then hide the login form.

Example: this will be inside the LoginForm code.

```
    MainView main = new MainView();
    MainView.Show();
    this.Visilble = false // or LoginForm.Visible = false
```

Comment: I see that you have edited the question, but didnt comment if my answer worked for you or not. If not, give more details of what you want to achieve.